# Class C inherits Class B and Class A. Class B also inherits Class A

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, derived-class

I want to log messages from both a base class B and a derived class C, being distinct about which class has logged the message:

```
#include "iostream"

class Logger {
public:
    Logger(std::string name) : name_(name) {}
    void log(std::string msg) { std::cout << name_ << ": " << msg << std::endl; }
private:
    std::string name_;
};

class B : public Logger {
public:
    B() : Logger("Class B" ) {}
    void doSomethingInB() {
        log("B doing something");
    }
};

class C : public B, public Logger {
public:
    C() : Logger("Class C" ) {}
    void doSomethingInC() {
        log("C doing something");
    }
};

int main() {
    B* b = new B();
    C* c = new C();

    b->doSomethingInB(); // I want this to output: Class B: B doing something

    c->doSomethingInC();
    c->doSomethingInB(); // I also want this to output: Class B: B doing something

    return 0;
}
```

I get the error "direct base ‘Logger’ inaccessible in ‘C’ due to ambiguity [enabled by default]" which is self-explanatory.

What different model can I implement to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use virtual inheritance like shown in the answer of Sam Cristall, but that will make only one `Logger` object in an instance of `C`, with the side effect that the log will not output the correct name (you also found this problem in a comment of this answer).

### Composition

One solution would be to use composition instead of inheritance:

```
class B
{
private:
    Logger log;
// ...
};
```

Probably the simplest solution. You can see a [**live example here**](https://ideone.com/vwS6sO).

### Inheritance

Another solution is to make the base classes different, here by using CRTP. That is:

```
template<typename T>
class LoggerImp : public Logger
{
public:
    LoggerImp(const std::string& n) : Logger(n) {}
};

class B : private LoggerImp<B>
{
private:
    typedef LoggerImp<B> LL;

public:
    B() : LoggerImp<B>("Class B" ) {}

    void doSomethingInB()
    {
        LL::log("B doing something");
    }
};

class C : public B, private LoggerImp<C>
{
private:
    typedef LoggerImp<C> LL;

public:
    C() : LoggerImp<C>("Class C" ) {}

    void doSomethingInC()
    {
        LL::log("C doing something");
    }
};
```

Some notes:

- I used private inheritance because as I understand your problem the logger is useful only to `B` or `C`, not owner of these objects.
- The CRTP is used to disambiguate the base names. It is not sufficient but help a lot in your problem
- The typedef is for readability. The fact that the logger bases have different names allows to correctly typedef them, permitting us to call the correct log function.
- A typedef in a derived class hides a typedef in the base class (provided they're for the same name). So you can use the same code for logging in different classes.
- You can also make the `Logger` class directly a CRTP.
- You can see [**a live example here**](https://ideone.com/lFVfxU).

Comment: Very in-depth and great notes too. Love the CRTP use. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** In response to your requirement of `c->doSomethingInB();` needing to print `Class B: B doing something`, consider composition over inheritance, since you need B to act as its own subclass, its logger is really not the same as C's (unless there are more requirements at play here).  Example:

```
class Logger {
public:
    Logger(std::string name) : name_(name) {}
    void log(std::string msg) { std::cout << name_ << ": " << msg << std::endl; }
private:
    std::string name_;
};

class B {
public:
    B() : logger_("Class B" ) {}
    void doSomethingInB() {
        logger_.log("B doing something");
    }
private:
  Logger logger_;
};

class C : public B {
public:
    C() : logger_("Class C" ) {}
    void doSomethingInC() {
        logger_.log("C doing something");
    }
private:
  Logger logger_;
};
```

Comment: That's close to what I want (at least compilable). The output though is:
`Class B: B doing something
Class C: C doing something
Class C: B doing something` when what I really want is:
`Class B: B doing something
Class C: C doing something
Class B: B doing something`

Comment: @user1088084 I missed that requirement.  See my edit, which uses composition instead of inheritance to achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That requirement was not obvious in the first rev of my code so it was easy to miss.